# Como capturar un elemento seleccionado desde un combobox llenado desde un BD

Tags: c#, sql

necesito ayuda con un poco de codigo. Resulta que tengo un combobox que relleno utilizando una base de datos:

```
private void frmMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //TEXT BOX DISABLED
        txtDv.Enabled = false;
        txtNombre.Enabled = false;
        txtApellido.Enabled = false;
        txtCorreo.Enabled = false;
        txtTelefono.Enabled = false;

        //LLENAR COMBOBOX DESDE BD
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source = DESKTOP-0PSJQKP; initial Catalog = BDControlEPP; User = sa; Password = a123456"))
        {
            try
            {
                string query = "select idItem, nombreItem from tblItems";
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(query, conn);
                conn.Open();
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                da.Fill(ds, "Items");
                cbItems.DisplayMember = "nombreItem";
                cbItems.ValueMember = "idItem";
                cbItems.DataSource = ds.Tables["Items"];

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }
        }

    }
```

Y necesito capturar el elemento seleccionado en el combobox con un boton AGREGAR que tengo al lado, ademas de un cuadro de texto al lado que indicara la cantidad que quiero de ese elemento e insertarlo a una Listview en el mismo form.

Quedo atento a cualquier respuesta, saludos!

Comment: Ya probaste usando: `cbItems.SelectedValue` ?

Comment: Si pero solamente me agrega la primera columna de los datos que tengo en la base de datos de dicho elemento, necesito que traiga todos los elementos de la tabla del elemento seleccionado en el combobox.

Comment: No entiendo bien tu pregunta, lo que deseas es que cuando selecciones el valor del combobox, todos los datos relacionados a este valor te lo muestre, pero esos datos que deseas que muestres donde se encuentran ? en otra tabla de la base de datos?

Comment: Lo primero exactamente, que cuando seleccione el valor del combobox, todos sus datos los traiga al ListView. Los datos estan guardados en una tabla en la base de datos.

Comment: Para eso deberías hacer algo como esto: en el evento `ValueChanged` del `cbItems` hacer otra consulta ejemplo asi: `select * from TuTabla where codigo= + cbItems.SelectedValue.ToString()` cuando ejecutes esa consulta tendrás todos los datos que pertenecen a ese Id del combo que seleccionaste.

Comment: Y luego como los agregaria al listview mediante el boton?

Comment: Que tipo de datos son los que deseas asignar al `ListView` ?

Answer (score 1):

Si no te interprete mal para obtener el valor de un ComboBox tenes 3 opciones..

Obtener el texto escrito en el combo

```
string texto = comboBox1.SelectedText
```

Obtener el miembro de valor de la opción seleccionada en el combobox

```
string miembro = comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString();
```

Por último, obtener el índice de posición del elemento seleccionado

```
int posicion = comboBox1.SelectedIndex;
```

Sin embargo por lo que veo en los comentarios, si lo que necesitas es obtener el resto de los valores en base al miembro de valor del comboBox, lo que deberías hacer es suscribir el ComboBox al evento **SelectedIndexChanged** y cada vez que ocurra ese evento realizar la query que necesites en función del valor obtenido en el comboBox